# What do "e" "-" "C" and "E" mean in this output?

Tags: molecular-biology, bioinformatics, proteins, database

I have given an input of this protein sequence:

```
MEPVDPRLEPWKHPGSQPKTACTTCYCKKCCFHCQVCFTTKALGISYGRKKRRQRRRPPQGSQTHQVSLSKQPTSQPRGDPTGPKE
```

from [this](http://scratch.proteomics.ics.uci.edu/) website  along with the option of COBEpro. Now the output sent by this site to my email is as follows:

```
Name: temp_prot

Amino Acids:
MEPVDPRLEPWKHPGSQPKTACTTCYCKKCCFHCQVCFTTKALGISYGRKKRRQRRRPPQGSQTHQVSLSKQPTSQPRGDPTGPKE

Predicted Continuous B-cell Epitopes:

MOST LIKELY EPITOPES:

0.82848577 39 TKALGIS CCCCCEE eee-e-e

0.82036375 39 TKALGI CCCCCE eee-e-

0.76503265 38 TTKALGI ECCCCCE eeee-e-

0.73178638 73 TSQPRGDP CCCCCCCC -eeeeeee

…
```

and a few more. Now can you tell me, if I consider the very first result, I was able to find `TKALGIS` in the parent sequence but could not find `CCCCCEE`. What is this `CCCCCEE`?
And what does this `eee-e-e` mean?

Comment: have you tried other software to verify?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CCCEEE *etc.* are the secondary structural elements. In this case, the `C` refers to non-strand and non-helix regions *i.e* loop regions rather than a coiled region. The `C` or `E` [usually](http://biostat.jhsph.edu/~iruczins/teaching/260.841/notes/c9.6.pdf) refers to whether the residue is coiled (`C`) or part of a strand (`E`). `H` would be used to denote a helix, however, in the question, it appears that there are no helices. These letters are often different in different software: it's merely a point of semantics between different software.

`e` or `-` refers to if the amino acid at that position is exposed or not (`-` = buried).

For the method, [here is the COBEpro paper](http://peds.oxfordjournals.org/content/22/3/113.full?keytype=ref&ijkey=AnJNyFmdbTK9mDF), although it does seem very technical. The [help page](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~baldig/scratch/explanation.html) has more easily accessible information on the output.

Comment: And how is the predicted antigenic propensity score plotted?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Perhaps open a new question.